# how can you cut it so that when to cubes are inside of each other one of the cubes disapear and leaves a hole in the other cybe?

Tags: modeling

how to do it?

whats the short cut?

whats the tool?

Comment: Do you mean you want a hollow cube but with walls (use one cube and a solidify modifier) or one cube cutting out some part of another cube (boolean difference) or something else entirely?

Comment: Do the geometries' surfaces need to intersect or do you want one totally inside the other?

Comment: here is a tutorial for that: https://youtu.be/ZQrq2DJqHgY.  just wait until it is uploaded

Comment: @  Chris, I guess what you show is rather a booltool option than a looptools function?